# Ansible shell - How to connect to hosts with custom credentials

Tags: shell, authentication, ansible

My goal is to execute a shell command on different hosts with credentials given directly from the playbook. Until now I have tried two things.

Attempt one:

```yaml
- name: test
    shell:
      command: "whoami"
    with_items: "{{lookup('file', '../files/deviceList.txt').splitlines()}}"
    delegate_to: "{{item.split(';')[0]}}"
    args:
      ansible_connection: network_cli
      ansible_network_os: ios
      ansible_user: "{{ cred_ios_r_user }}"
      ansible_password: "{{ cred_ios_r_pass }}"
```

Attempt 2:

```yaml
- name: set default credentials
  set_fact:
    ansible_connection: network_cli
    ansible_network_os: ios
    ansible_user: "{{ cred_ios_r_user }}"
    ansible_password: "{{ cred_ios_r_pass }}"
  with_items: "{{lookup('file', '../files/deviceList.txt').splitlines()}}"
  delegate_to: "{{item.split(';')[0]}}"

- name: test
  shell:
    command: "whoami"
  with_items: "{{lookup('file', '../files/deviceList.txt').splitlines()}}"
  delegate_to: "{{item.split(';')[0]}}"
```

The Username in the variable `{{cred_ios_r_user}}` is `'User1'`. But when I look in the Output from Ansible, it tells me it used the default ssh user named `"SSH_User"`.

What do I need to change so that Ansible takes the given credentials?

Answer (score 1):

first thing you should to check - its "remote_user" attribute of module:

```
- name: DigitalOcean | Disallow root SSH access
  remote_user: root
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/ssh/sshd_config
              regexp="^PermitRootLogin"
              line="PermitRootLogin no"
              state=present
  notify: Restart ssh
```

Next thing, its ssh_keys. By default, your connections have your own private key, but you can override it by the extraargs of ansible-playbook command, of variables in inventory-file or job-vars:

```
vars:
  ansible_ssh_user: "root"
  ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "{{ role_path }}/files/ansible.key"
```

so if you want, you can set custom keys you have in vars or files:

```
- name: DigitalOcean | Add Pub key
  remote_user: root
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ do_user }}"
    key: "{{ lookup('file', do_key_public) }}"
    state: present
```

you have take more information in my [auto-droplet-digitalocean-role](https://gitlab.com/deusops/ansible-roles/ansible-role-digitalocean)

Answer (score 1):

Your vars should be... vars available for your task, not arguments passed to the `shell` module. So in a nutshell:

```yaml
  - name: test
    vars:
      ansible_connection: network_cli
      ansible_network_os: ios
      ansible_user: "{{ cred_ios_r_user }}"
      ansible_password: "{{ cred_ios_r_pass }}"
    shell:
      command: "whoami"
    with_items: "{{ lookup('file', '../files/deviceList.txt').splitlines() }}"
    delegate_to: "{{ item.split(';')[0] }}"
```

Meanwhile this looks like a bad practice. You would normally use `add_host` to build an in-memory inventory with the correct hosts and credentials and then run your task using the natural host batch play loop. Something like

```yaml
- name: manage hosts
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  
  tasks:
    - name: add hosts to inventory
      add_host:
        name: "{{ item.split(';')[0] }}"
        groups:
          - my_custom_group
        ansible_connection: network_cli
        ansible_network_os: ios
        ansible_user: "{{ cred_ios_r_user }}"
        ansible_password: "{{ cred_ios_r_pass }}"
      with_items: "{{ lookup('file', '../files/deviceList.txt').splitlines() }}"

- name: run my command on all added hosts
  hosts: my_custom_group
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: test command
      shell: whoami
```

Alternativelly, you can create a full inventory from scratch from your csv file and use it directly or use/develop an inventory plugin that will read your csv file directly (like in [this example](https://github.com/nmake/inventory))